# How to respond to reviewers that ask you to "look again at your results" without providing further details?

Tags: peer-review, review-articles

Recently my research paper got major revision in which one of the reviewer ask me to look again at the results I have derived without pointing to any specific item of results. I have double checked my results and all results found to be correct and now I am confused that what actually reviewer is trying to say as he/she did not specifically mentioned nature of error in my results.

So how should I respond? (The second reviewer is satisfied with my results)

Comment: What is the field?

Comment: Sometimes you make mistakes that are absolutely obvious to everyone reading it, but not to the person who wrote it.

Answer (score 7):

Email the editor to ask for clarification. They are the person you need to satisfy. If they don't understand what is needed either, they will either get in touch with the reviewer to ask, or they will tell you not to worry.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the first reviewer could not understand the derivation or the paper (perhaps it is outside his/her field)? If they have found something wrong, I believe they would (and should) have pointed it out! If you are comfortable with the results and as you said "double checked them", you should be fine. You can address his comment by stating that the results have been rechecked and validated (if possible) - as my advisor says, a vague question requires a general answer!

I will play the devil advocates for a second. I understand that the second reviewer is happy with the results (but, that does not assure us (the readers), that the results are fine). For all we know, s/he did not even go through them! Or maybe they did, but could not see the point of the first reviewer (if any). The first reviewer's comment is vague and to be it to rest, perhaps, you can ask a colleague of yours (who knows your field) to go over them again?